# Simple script to set origin of FBX files

Tags: scripting

I am trying to understand how to work with multiple files in Blender scripting. For some reason, I cannot get this to work properly.

The script I am trying here is super simple. I have a bunch of FBX files in a folder. Each FBX I want to set the origin to the volume center. After that I want to save it as [filename]_converted.fbx.

This is my code:

```
import bpy
import os

# Set the folder path where your FBX files are located
folder_path = r"path_to_folder"

# List all FBX files in the folder
fbx_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(".fbx")]

# Loop through each FBX file in the folder
for fbx_file in fbx_files:
    # Create a full path to the FBX file
    fbx_path = os.path.join(folder_path, fbx_file)

    # Clear existing data
    bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

    # Import the FBX file
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_path)

    # Check if there are selected objects
    if bpy.context.selected_objects:
        # Select the first imported object
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        bpy.context.object.select_set(True)

        # Set the pivot point to the center of mass volume
        bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CENTER_OF_VOLUME', center='BOUNDS')

        # Create a new file name for saving
        new_fbx_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "centered_" + fbx_file)

        # Export the FBX file with the centered pivot
        bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=new_fbx_path, use_selection=True)

        # Remove the imported object
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = None
        bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
        bpy.ops.object.delete()

        # Clear existing data again
        bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

# Print a message when the process is done
print("Script completed.")
```

Sadly, I always get an error like:

```
FBX version: 7400
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 22, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'
```

All FBX files contain at least one object.

[image: This is the structure of the FBX]

I do not see how I can get this to work. Maybe it has something to do with the structure of the FBX? Any ideas?